# how to concatenate within a query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to concatenate within a query a must a create a function to do that before I perform my query.

I have want to add the numerals "00" to my `hours[$j]` array as I send the query in. I know I could do it before the query, just curious of how to do it within the query. I've tried several combinations of "" . in my attempts to join them but I can't figure it out.

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO leaders (name, shift_date, shift_time) 
 VALUES ('$name', '$date', '$hours[$j] . 00')";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO leaders (name, shift_date, shift_time) 
 VALUES ('$name', '$date', '" . $hours[$j] . "00" ."')";
```

Or just :

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO leaders (name, shift_date, shift_time) 
 VALUES ('$name', '$date', '" . $hours[$j] . "00')";
```

Answer (score 1):

or:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO leaders (name, shift_date, shift_time) 
 VALUES ('$name', '$date', CONCAT('" . $hours[$j] . "', '00'))";
```